# How do I get the asdoc output table to show both the variable labels and value labels in Stata?

Tags: label, stata, asdoc

I'm trying to make a table using asdoc that will include both the value labels and the variable labels in the output. When I run the following line of code in Stata

```
asdoc list progname progtype progterm publicprivate cohortsize grereq, label
```

I get this in the console (no variable labels):
[image]

But in the word doc, it comes out looking like this (has variable labels but no value labels in the table cells):
[image]

How do I get both the variable and value labels in the table?

Answer (score 0):

The last update of asdoc was on April 10, 2021. I announced the following in that update.

It is now almost three years that I have been developing asdoc and constantly adding features to it. With the addition of **_docx** and **xl()** classes to Stata, it is high time to add support for native *docx* and *xlsx* output to asdoc. Also, given that there exists a significant number of LaTeX users, asdoc should be able to create LaTeX documents.  It gives me immense pleasure to announce asdocx that is not only more flexible in making customized tables, but also creates documents in native docx, **xlsx**, **html**, and **tex** formats. If you have enjoyed and find asdoc useful, please consider buying a copy of asdocx to support its development. Details related to asdocx can be found on  [this page](https://asdocx.com/).

I am still committed to fixing bugs / issues in asdoc. However, I think it makes more sense to me to add features to asdocx than asdoc, given that asdocx supports all latest developments in Word, Excel and LaTeX.

The requested feature is already available in asdocx. See the following example.

```
sysuse nlsw88
asdocx list industry age race married grade south in 1/20, replace label
```

[image: table produced by asdocx for the list command]

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I have a limited budget and don't know that purchasing asdocx would be the best option for me. Are there other packages that could give me the result I'm trying to achieve?